# Web3 event showing error and application is unable to continue

Tags: python, web3py

```
def listenForTokens(lastRunTime):
    try:
        event_filter = contract.events.PairCreated.createFilter(fromBlock='latest')
    except:
        print("Error skipped")
        pass
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(
            asyncio.gather(
                tokenLoop(event_filter, 0, lastRunTime)))       
    except:
        print("Error skipped")
        pass
    finally:
        try:
            listenForTokens()
        except:
            print("Error skipped")
            pass


lastRunTime = datetime.datetime.now()
listenForTokens(lastRunTime)

input("")
```

These are a few lines of code in a python application that are throwing the "Error Skipped" text everytime i run the program and it won't continue after that. This is a Web3 method which i am struggling to alter to get it to work.

I tried to change the syntax of the method but to no avail, It still threw the same error.

Comment: You have the same error text in three places.  Which one is being printed?

Comment: All 3 are being printed